# How to determine the type of a file by content?

Tags: file, mime-types, file-extension

If I have a file without an extension, how can I determine what type of file it is (music, video, text, etc.)? Are there any hints to determine a file's extension depending on its character components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looking for the unix "file" command.  Luckily there a port available for windows:  [File](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)